# Dynamically created TextBoxes inside a Panel is inaccessible by name

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have added some dynamically created TextBox elements inside a panel as follows

```
            for(int index=0; index<textBoxArray.Length; index++)
            {
                panel_textbox.Controls.Add(textBoxArray[index]);
            }
```

Where the textBoxArray holds TextBox objects with names like txt_1, txt_2
Now when I'm trying to access the textbox using following code

```
panel_textbox.Controls.Find("txt_1")[0].Visible = true;
```

It can't find the TextBox. I'm using C# and it is a windows application.

Comment: And you have given atleast one of the TextBoxes the name "txt_1"? Aka you have set its name Property to "txt_1"?

Comment: Yes i did, I named them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search all children.

```
panel_textbox.Controls.Find("txt_1",true)[0].Visible = true;
```

or

```
this.Controls.Find("txt_1",true)[0].Visible = true;
```

Comment: yeah tried with all children but that didn't work. Even though I'm seeing the textboxes inside the panel MessageBox.Show(panel_textbox.Controls.Count) showing 0

Comment: @AngshuGuha: Show where you assign names for textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have done following, I find no problem with code....10 textboxes are visible in my Panel in WinForm application

```
 TextBox[] array = new TextBox[10];int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 45;i+=5 )
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox()
            {

                Name = "txt_" + count,
                Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10+i,15+i,0,0),

                Text="Hello "+count,
                Height = 10,
                Width = 100
            };
            array[count++] = textBox;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length;i++ )
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(array[i]);
        }
           (panel1.Controls.Find("txt_0", false)[0]).Visible = false;
```